# JDO copy object

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I need to copy GAE save data object and need to change it field value and save it as different object.

Is there any way to copy objects without  copying KEy value?

Thank You

Comment: so does the posted solution answer your question? because you should "accept" the answer in that case

Comment: @DataNucleus I used "java object clone" as a solution.

Comment: @Chandana When you find another solution you can post it your self and then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Call pm.makeTransient() and its then in transient lifecycle state. Then just update the id and whatever else and call pm.makePersistent.